# OpenCV Python findHomography srcPoint input not compatible

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to find the transformation of an loaded image to a plane detected off of a marker so that I can transform it to appear perpendicular to the marker plane. I am having trouble putting inputs to `cv2.findHomography`. Please help to change the input format to this function

Here is my code that is causing issue:

```
muffinImg = cv2.imread('muffin.jpg',0)
muffinCoords = np.zeros((4,2), np.float32)
muffheight, muffwidth = muffinImg.shape
muffinCoords[0] = (0,muffwidth)
muffinCoords[1] = (muffwidth,muffheight)
muffinCoords[2] = (0,muffheight)
muffinCoords[3] = (0,0)

found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(frameLeft, (5,4),None)

if (found):
    corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(grayframeLeft,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
    q = [(0,0)]*4
    q[0] = corners[0][0]
    q[1] = corners[3][0]
    q[2] = corners[19][0]
    q[3] = corners[16][0]

    retvalHomography, mask = cv2.findHomography(q, muffinCoords, cv2.RANSAC)
    cv2.warpPerspective(muffinImg, retvalHomography, (400, 500), muffinImg, cv2.INTER_NEAREST, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,  0)
```

I am getting this error on the `cv2.findHomography` line: `srcPoints is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

Here is what Microsoft Visual object inspection tool gives me

q: [image]

muffin: [image]

EDIT: I have some additional info about the inputs but I don't see how they are different, maybe I am just making a noob mistake: from here http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Anyone-have-a-Python2-example-using-estimateRigidTransform-td7322817.html.

One quick answer which might help (depending on what you are trying to do) is that the cv2.findHomography function does work from python. It returns 3x3 rather than 2x3 matrix but you will find coefficients in the bottom row close to either zero or one if the transform really is rigid so slice them off.

```
a=np.array([0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1],np.float32).reshape(-1,2) #small square 
b=a*2  #scale x2 
b+=0.5 #translate across and down 
H,matches=cv2.findHomography(a,b,cv2.RANSAC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `q` is not a numpy array.  Try converting it to an array before passing it to `cv2.findHomography()`.

I don't know the cv2 API well enough to be sure, but I think you should change this:

```
q = [(0,0)]*4
q[0] = corners[0][0]
q[1] = corners[3][0]
q[2] = corners[19][0]
q[3] = corners[16][0]
```

to something like this:

```
q = np.zeros((4,2), dtype=np.float32)
q[0] = corners[0][0]
q[1] = corners[3][0]
q[2] = corners[19][0]
q[3] = corners[16][0]
```

After a brief look at the cv2 docs, I think `corners` is an array with shape n x 2, so those assignments don't make much sense to me.  `corners[0][0]` (which could be written more succinctly as `corner[0,0]`) is the first coordinate of the first corner, i.e. `corner[0][0]` is a scalar.  Why are you assigning only the first coordinate to `q[0]`?  What is the intent of that code?  I suspect it could be simplified to:

```
q = corners[[0, 3, 19, 16]]
```

For example:

```
In [12]: corners = np.arange(40).reshape(20,2).astype(np.float32)

In [13]: corners
Out[13]: 
array([[  0.,   1.],
       [  2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.],
       [ 14.,  15.],
       [ 16.,  17.],
       [ 18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.],
       [ 22.,  23.],
       [ 24.,  25.],
       [ 26.,  27.],
       [ 28.,  29.],
       [ 30.,  31.],
       [ 32.,  33.],
       [ 34.,  35.],
       [ 36.,  37.],
       [ 38.,  39.]], dtype=float32)

In [14]: q = corners[[0, 3, 19, 16]]

In [15]: q
Out[15]: 
array([[  0.,   1.],
       [  6.,   7.],
       [ 38.,  39.],
       [ 32.,  33.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: thanks this helped clear things up around my code actually. turns out I was pulling calibration parameters that were 10x error than my best result. I am still confused on why my image is not being affected as I apply `warpPerspective` after finding the transformation matrix with `findHomography`